# Can I return a squash serve on the volley?

Tags: rules, serve, squash

When my opponent is serving in squash, if I want to return the serve, can I volley this ball back to them? That is, without the ball hitting the floor (opponent serves > front wall > I volley the ball back).

If yes, do I have to stay within my own serving box? How many of my feet have to remain in the box, one or both?

If no, can I cross the T-line in front of my box if I keep one foot in it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can volley.  A legal serve is defined in [Rules of Squash](http://www.worldsquash.org/ws/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/170620_Rules-of-Singles-Squash-2014-V2014-04.pdf).  Defining where the ball must land is:

> 5.7.4 the ball, **unless volleyed by the receiver**, bounces for the first time in the opposite quarter-court without touching any line; and
>   [...]

Volleying allows the serve to be legal without landing on the ground.

The service box and quarter-court lines are limits for the server and the serve, not the receiver.  I don't see it explicitly mentioned in the rules, but the receiver should be able to stand anywhere that doesn't interfere with the service.

Comment: This is something I have done before, although I've not stepped over the line to volley very early. It's a very attacking shot.